# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined

Tags: javascript

I am trying to do an image carousel slide however I am catching an error => `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'clientWidth' of undefined` <- when I console.log(counter) and press the button it does not work

```js
const carouselSlide = document.querySelector('.carousel-slide');
const carouselImages = document.querySelectorAll('.caroulse-slide img');

//Button
const prevBtn = document.querySelector('#prevBtn');
const nextBtn = document.querySelector('#nextBtn');

//Counter
let counter = 1;
const size = carouselImages[0].clientWidth;
carouselSlide.style.transform = 'translateX(' + (-size * counter) + 'px)';

//Button Listeners
nextBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
  carouselSlide.style.transition = "transform 0.4s ease-in-out";
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
});
```

Comment: `carouselImages` is an empty NodeList, `document.querySelectorAll('.caroulse-slide img')` didn't find anything. Maybe the class name in the selector should be `carousel-slide`? Also, it's possible, that you're running this code before the elements are parsed?

Comment: If these classes are really present .caroulse-slide img , then you need to call this script once your DOM has loaded completely.